# phpldapadmin uidNumber stopped auto-updating on new user creation

Tags: openldap, ldap

We are having an issue that just started this morning.

It seems our phpldapadmin (1.2.04) interface has stopped auto-incrementing the uidNumber on new user creation. Basically we are stuck at uidNumber 5495 even though that uidNumber already exists.

Things I have tried:

- Modifying 'config.php'

  > $servers->setValue('auto_number','min',array('uidNumber'=>5000,'gidNumber'=>7000));

  to

  > $servers->setValue('auto_number','min',array('uidNumber'=>5500,'gidNumber'=>7000));

  This jumped the new uidNumber as expected, but after creating a a user, the next user was still getting uidNumber 5500
- Configured the template being used to make uidNumber not 'ReadOnly'.  This allowed me to manually set the uidNumber but is not prefered.
- Searching using the phpldapadmin interface for uidNumber=* currently returns 501 results.

The template is using the php.GetNextNumber tag as follows:

```
<value>=php.GetNextNumber(/;uidNumber)</value>
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

-R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging, I found a hard-coded query limit in the 'lib/ds_ldap.php' file.

I modified the following line from:

> $size_limit = 500;

to

> $size_limit = 1000;

To match my OpenLDAP Servers' Query sizelimit.
This may not have been the right place to do it, but in the end this is working now.